# How to hide the . and .. from ls

Tags: bash, tail, cut

When I run `ls -l` on a directory, I see an entry titled '.' How can I remove the row containing '.'  from   the output?

```
ls -latr /foo | tail -n5 
-rw-rw-r--  1 guest bar      59169 Aug 20 12:22 foobar
-rw-rw-r--  1 guest bar      59169 Aug 20 12:23 bar1
-rw-rw-r--  1 guest bar      59169 Aug 20 12:24 foobar42
-rw-rw-r--  1 guest bar      59169 Aug 20 12:25 foo
drwxrws---  8 guest bar    102400 Aug 20 12:26 .
```

I'm thinking cut should work, but I can't find the right syntax.

```
ls -latr |tail -n5|cut -d'.'  
ls -latr |tail -n5|cut -d.
```

Comment: Because that's what the `-a` option means: list everything including `.` and `..`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming GNU or BSD ls:

```
ls -lAtr /foo
```

Comment: Actually the `-A` option has been added to the latest version of the POSIX standard (2008) so is becoming more and more portable (note that `-A` excludes both `.` and `..`).

Comment: Excellent, that does what I am looking for.

Comment: Note that if the directory contains files or directories starting with `.` (so `.foo` as an example) they will get listed with `-A` (which is probably what you want!) If not, drop the `-a` and `-A` options all together.

Answer (score 1):

... and if ls is not GNU ls,

```
ls -latr ... | grep -v '^d.* \.$'
```

Comment: `-A` has existed on BSD, Linux (including BusyBox) and Solaris for a long time.